# Code is skipping and returning back to calling function

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to get GPS data in my Xamarin app but it skips the code after await and returns to calling function here is my code.I have seen another related question but it is not working.Here is my code

```
namespace googleMap
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public string apidata;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        apiDataAsync();
    }
    public async void apiDataAsync()
    {
        await MapLoadAsync();            
    }
    private async Task MapLoadAsync()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 20;
        var ticks = 10000;
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(ticks);
        var location =  await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), null, true);
        var latitude = location.Latitude.ToString();
        var longitude = location.Longitude.ToString();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: It's not that it *skips* the code after `await` - it's that that code will be scheduled and executed when the task returned by `GetPositionAsync` has completed. You're effectively *starting* something happening. You really want to call `MapLoadAsync` from your constructor and await the result, but you can't use `await` in constructors. You could potentially write a static factory method instead - it's hard to know exactly what your requirements are though.

Comment: What is `MapLoadAsync` actually doing? You are getting the latitude and longitude, converting them to strings and then dropping them on the floor.

Comment: @pstrjds I didn't post it but after calculating it is drawing pin on map

Comment: You could also override the OnAppearing method of ContentPage asyncly and await apiDataAsync in this one. try this line in your mainpage: `protected override async void OnAppearing() { await apiDataAsync(); }`. This is called after the page has appeard, in most cases briefly after the ctor finished

Answer (score 0):

It is skipping because when it hits

```
var location =  await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), null, true);
```

the method returns to the caller until the await expression is done. But you are not awaiting it in the constructor (because you can't), so it just continues, and the Task get's lost.

Your best bet would be to create a factory, which would have an async method to create a new MainPage, and the factory would `await apiDataAsync()`.

But all this only applies, if what apiDataAsync does is long. If it's very quick, than don't bother, and just call locator.GetPositionAsync synchronously.

```
var location = locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), null, true).Result;
```